# Converting C# JSON POST to SWIFT 3

Tags: c#, ios, swift

I have been trying to convert this code from C# to Swift 3.0 with no luck on syntax.  The code is straight from https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/Home/Index/LanguageExamples but has no Swift examples.

Thanks for any help or pointers.

```
string text = "3GNDA13D76S000000;5XYKT3A12CG000000;";
string url = @"https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/DecodeVINValuesBatch/";

var nameValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
nameValues.Add("data", text);
nameValues.Add("format", "json");
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);

// using FormUrlEncodedContent
var name = new FormUrlEncodedContent(nameValues);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new 
MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
System.Threading.CancellationToken token = new 
System.Threading.CancellationToken();

try {
    var tmp = client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress, name, token).Result;
    var result = tmp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
} catch (Exception err) {
    // error handling
}
```

Comment: take a look at using Alamofire for networking requests in Swift.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+%5Balamofire%5D+post

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll check out Alamofire for this as well as the link provided.  I am still new to Swift and JSON confuses me big time, so thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

I hard coded the url with a test VIN and this worked for me, thanks for the help!

```
    let url: String = "https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/DecodeVIN/WBY2Z2C52GV676091?format=JSON"


    Alamofire.request(url, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON {
        (response) in
        print(response.request as Any)  // original URL request
        print(response.response?.allHeaderFields as Any) // URL response
        print(response.result.value as Any)   // result of response serialization
    }
```